# How to bind multiple events to one function python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, event-binding

Is there any better way to do the following:

```py
master.bind("<Button-1>", function)
master.bind("<Button-2>", function)
master.bind("<Button-3>", function)
```

I want to bind 3 events to one function in less than three lines of code. I know that this probably is not possible. I am just wondering if you could do something like this:

```py
master.bind("<Button-1>" and "<Button-2>" and "<Button-3>", function)
```

This doesn't work as it only binds `"<Button-3>"`. Using `or` instead of `and` only binds `"<Button-1>"`.

**Edit:** I can use the generic `"<Button>"` like:

```py
master.bind("<Button>", function)
```

I want a more generic example, like one that can be used for `"<KP_0>"` and `"<Button-1>"`.

Comment: why do you need to do it in less than three lines of code?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to make it shorter, and this takes three lines of code, so I want it in less than three lines of code. This may not be possible. This question is purely exprerimental.

Comment: `[master.bind(button, function, add='+') for button in ["<Button-1>","<Button-2>","<Button-3>"]` could be a single line, but there is no reason to do this

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Tkinter supports this functionality due to it being essentially a loop.

If you really need your code all on one line try this.

```
master.bind("<Button-1>", function), master.bind("<Button-2>", function), master.bind("<Button-3>", function)
```

Not Exactly the best way to do things but it should work.

Comment: This technically works, but I want to write less code, and this uses the same amount of code.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that tkinter doesn't support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```py
for b in ["<Button-1>", "<Button-2>", "<Button-3>"]: master.bind(b, function)
```

There really isn't a prettier way to do it with Tkinter itself. Either you make a for loop and reuse the parts that stay the same, but I'd recommend just writing it all out.